# Import from Wufoo

Tags: cognito-forms

How can I import or download a form from Wufoo?

I cannot find information on this website describing the process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [FAQ for Wufoo Users](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/7/faq/#tagged-faqs-for-wufoo-users)!

The FAQ includes a link to the Wufoo Form Importer and other useful information for new [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) users.